# filtering the records in the second grid according to the selection in the first

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

i've header and detail rad grids. when i click a record from header rad grid, it must be filled detail grid. how to do this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more details or frame the question again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to do something like [this](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/selectedvalue/defaultcs.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Check out these demos, this demo and the other demos listed on the left: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/detailtabledatabind/defaultcs.aspx

Basically, set the HierarchyLoadMode="ServerOnDemand" for the MasterTableView.  Then add a DetailTableDataBind event handler on the  RadGrid.  This fires every time you expand the header record (by default, the child gets loaded when expanded, not clicked).  If you wanted to expand on click, you may be able to programmably expand the table.

Also, if you set the EnablePostBackOnRowClick="true" and ClientSettings AllowRowSelect="true", this posts back when clicking on the row, so that handles that part of the equation.

HTH.